# How to exclude resource package from being build into jar Maven?

Tags: maven, jar

HI i am building an project into a jar file from maven but i want some resource  packages not to be included in that jar. Rather i want to build two seperate jars one that contain project and another with those excluded packages. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using [dependency:copy-dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) there are two options that will help you:

- [excludeClassifiers](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html#excludeClassifiers): Comma Separated list of Classifiers to exclude. Empty String indicates don't exclude anything (default).
- [excludeScope](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html#excludeScope) Scope to exclude. An Empty string indicates no scopes (default).

I use this for example to exclude jsp-api.jar from my Struts2 war project. This jar is needed to run StrutsTestCase tests but if it's included in the war, it conflicts with Tomcat lib directori, wich already contains jsp-api.jar

Setting my dependency as this in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>        
    </dependency>
```

And my maven-dependency plugin as this:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib</outputDirectory>
                <excludeScope>provided</excludeScope>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I've solved my excluding jar problem when deploying on Tomcat